# How to display String variable containing spaces in value field of a form in JSP?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I can easily display the value of a String variable in the text field of a form in JSP by using value = <%= name %> but if the String variable contains more than one word, i.e., if it contains spaces, then only the first word is getting displayed and not the entire sentence.

Here is the code with the output.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    String abc = "this is a string with spaces";
%>

<h3>Displaying string outside form: </h3>
<p> <%= abc %> </p>

<h3>Displaying string inside form:</h3>
<form>
    <input type = "text" value = <%= abc %>>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

How can I display the entire sentence in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quoting it.

```
<input type="text" value="<%= abc %>">
```

You can also use single quotes

```
<input type="text" value='<%= abc %>'>
```

Finally, you shouldn't be using scriptlets.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I know this tech is not much in use anymore. Unfortunately, my syllabus at school is a bit outdated. Nevertheless, thanks once again!

Comment: @SthitaprajnaMishra you _did_ quote every other single attribute in the shown code, but it did not occur to you it might be important for this one in particular, when it might contain spaces ...?